# Problema com Column-Gap

Tags: html, css, grid

Boa noite. Estou tendo um problema no meu *CSS*.. Preciso criar duas colunas, uma de texto, e outra com imagem, porém as colunas **não alinham** (erro no CSS, mas não consigo arrumar);

**Segue a linha do código:**

*HTML:*

```
<section class="section-a">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h1>Esse é o smartphone que mudará a história da fotografia.</h1>
            <p>
            Conheça o Galaxy S20, o S20+ e o S20 Ultra. Eles contam com o revolucionário 8K Video Snap, que muda a forma como você grava vídeos e tira fotos.1 Com a segurança do Samsung Knox, uma bateria inteligente, um processador poderoso e um espaço de armazenamento enorme, os 3 modelos do Galaxy S20 revelam um novo mundo para os smartphones.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Leia Mais</a>
            <div>
            <img src="images/s20.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.section-a .container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
column-gap: 3em;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua div que contém a imagem está dentro da  que deveria se posicionar à esquerda. Ela deve ficar dentro da class .container, porém deve ser irmã da div ao qual ficará ao lado. Segue código alterado:

```css
.section-a .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 5em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-a">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="coluna-1">
            <h1>Esse é o smartphone que mudará a história da fotografia.</h1>
            <p>
            Conheça o Galaxy S20, o S20+ e o S20 Ultra. Eles contam com o revolucionário 8K Video Snap, que muda a forma como você grava vídeos e tira fotos.1 Com a segurança do Samsung Knox, uma bateria inteligente, um processador poderoso e um espaço de armazenamento enorme, os 3 modelos do Galaxy S20 revelam um novo mundo para os smartphones.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Leia Mais</a>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna-2">
          <img src="images/s20.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
    </div>
```